# Hover over an icon to reveal specific content below?

Tags: hyperlink, hover, row

What's the best method of getting this result: when I hover over an icon-link (in a row of icons) the content below (specific to that icon) changes accordingly. Here's a picture of what I mean.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest jquery.It could give you easily some nice effects also

Comment: I'll look into it. Any link to a specific "how-to" for this kind of an endeavor?

Comment: Here a few simple stuff just to get the idea http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/jquery-image-hover-effects/

Comment: Thanks! I found a few jquery tutorials on YouTube as well.